# Laravel 4: prevent access to any file or folder except public

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm working on small project, and will host it on normal Godaddy host plan, the problem is:  all file system will be accessible through internet.

so, how can I prevent access to any folder or file except /public

```
CONTRIBUTING.md  
app/     
artisan  
bootstrap/   
composer.json    
composer.lock    
phpunit.xml  
public/  
server.php   
vendor/
```

thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not split the project up? Upload the contents of `public` to your document root and the rest somewhere else (like your home directory). Then just modify the two paths in the `public/index.php` file to point to the right locations, eg

```
$path = __DIR__ . '/../my-app';

require $path . '/bootstrap/autoload.php';

$app = require_once $path . '/bootstrap/start.php';
```

Comment: then protect the rest of files in "$path" using .htaccess ? or have better idea? thanks

Comment: @mwafi If they're not under the document root, they're not directly accessible. You won't have to do anything else

Comment: all file system under document root

Comment: @mwafi you sure about that? I haven't used GoDaddy in a while but I do recall that your home directory and the main site document root were not the same. I could be wrong :(

Comment: my root directory called "webroot", I can't browse or upload files outside it, and  all files and directories inside "webroot" is accessible through internet (no apache configurations allowed)

Comment: @mwafi This might help ~ http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/4175/specifying-a-new-default-document-root-on-your-hosting-account

Answer (score 2):

If you point your apache site document root to `/public`, there is no way people can access any other file in your application outside your public. Even if they try to do things like:

```
http://yoursite.com/../
```

**EDIT:**

This is not something you should rely on a framework to do, securing directories on your site is the web server job, so you need to find a solution on your server: virtual host, document root, web root, domain directory or even .htaccess configuration.

In some shared hosting companies you can do that easily, some have cPanel or Plesk, but other, like Hostgator, will give you just enough configuration so you can change your directory root to /public. Looks like GoDaddy doesn't help much if you don't have a cPanel account, but, still, there are tricks to help you doing it the way you should be doing: http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/4067/setting-up-a-non-web-accessible-root-folder. Probably there are others around.

Comment: Well, if your GoDaddy shared hosting has a cPanel you probably will be able to set the document root. This is a GoDaddy link teaching how to create a new domain on a shared hosting and it has a Document Root config, so I have to assume this is common, even for GoDaddy:  http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/8877/adding-addon-domains-to-your-cpanel-shared-hosting-account

Comment: no Godaddy does not provide cPanel and can't find any apache configurations in my account,  you mention setting root for multiple domain names hosted in same account but still root directory accessible through master domain.

Comment: I'm insisting because this is pretty basic stuff, I don't have a GoDaddy domain, but have a Hostgator and I just found how to do on it: http://puu.sh/8IUrF.png. I can't really believe you don't have something similar on GoDaddy. There even a way to set them for subdomains: http://puu.sh/8IU5y.jpg.

Comment: GoDadday talk about what you probably need to do: http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/4067/setting-up-a-non-web-accessible-root-folder.